# Specific Cross Validation with Random Forest

Tags: scikit-learn

Am using Random Forest with scikit learn.
RF overfits the data and prediction results are bad.

The overfit does NOT depend on the parameters of the RF:
   NBtree, Depth_Tree

Overfit happens with many different parameters (Tested it across grid_search).

To remedy:
    I tweak the initial data/ down sampling some results
    in order to affect the fitting (Manually pre-process noise sample).

```
Loop on random generation of RF fits, 

Get RF prediction on the  data for prediction
Select the model which best fits the "predicted data" (not the calibration data).
```

This Monte carlos is very consuming,
Just wondering if there is another way to do 
cross validation on random Forest ?  (ie NOT the hyper-parameter optimization).

EDITED

Comment: Just read the docs. Especially [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#grid-search).

Comment: Are you using oob_score or accuracy when you say that your model is overfitting?

Comment: Looking at the confusion matrix False Positive/Negative....

Training is OK.
But, Out of sample is not consistent good (usually bad, sometimes OK).

Answer (score 50):

Cross-Validation with any classifier in scikit-learn is really trivial:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy as np

# Initialize with whatever parameters you want to
clf = RandomForestClassifier()

# 10-Fold Cross validation
print np.mean(cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=10))
```

If you wish to run Grid Search, you can easily do it via the [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) class. In order to do so you will have to provide a `param_grid`, which according to the documentation is

> Dictionary with parameters names (string) as keys and lists of
> parameter settings to try as values, or a list of such dictionaries,
> in which case the grids spanned by each dictionary in the list are
> explored. This enables searching over any sequence of parameter
> settings.

So maybe, you could define your `param_grid` as follows:

```py
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [5, 10, 15, 20],
    'max_depth': [2, 5, 7, 9]
}
```

Then you can use the `GridSearchCV` class as follows

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

grid_clf = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, cv=10)
grid_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You can then get the best model using `grid_clf. best_estimator_`  and the best parameters using `grid_clf. best_params_`. Similarly you can get the grid scores using `grid_clf.cv_results_`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Question does not refer to Hyper-parameter optimization.

Comment: it should be
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
or
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

Comment: Fantastic explanantion! For some reason, the best "score" (`score={"AUC":"roc_auc","ACC":make_score(accuracy)}` is not in the `grid_clf.best_estimator_`, is there a reason why?

Comment: It may not be available because `AUC` is related to classification, not regression. If you are using a regression model, a different score (such as `f_score`) would likely be more appropriate.